# ASP .NET WebAPI default OWIN authentication - help clear things up

Tags: authentication, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin

I have some general/how-does-it-work-inside questions about WebAPI and OWIN (specifically, the default configuration which is set up when you create new WebAPI project in VS2013 and select Individual user account authentication). I did that, then I registered (using jQuery post) and even logged in (received token which I included in Authorization header, receiving access to protected resource. I just have some more questions about it:

1. Are my data stored inside authentication token? I know my password isn't, but is token containing encrypted data, or is just a random string? These are the only 2 options that I can think of: either token contains encrypted data (userId, expiration date, etc.) and server app deciphers it and grants me access to resources, or token is a random string and all user data are stored on server (token is used as a key to obtain correct user data entry). If the second theory is right, the token <-> userData lookup must be stored somewhere - is it session, cache or database maybe?
2. If i wanted to make a RESTful API, what about Roles, etc. (in general - data beyond simple who-are-you identification that I need for every request)? Again: first thing that comes to mind is to store them inside token. But if the data grows large isn't that too much overhead to send with each request (plus headers themselves probably are limited in size)? Second thing is using external OAuth service (like Facebook or Twitter) - if the user authenticates using external token, I can't control what information does it contain. Alternative is to get the data I need from the database each time, but isn't it bad practice? Every single request would need an extra database call to collect user's role and check if he even has access to this particular part of application. I could store it in session, but RESTful API is supposed to be stateless.

Thanks for any help as I'm just starting to dig into OAuth and WebAPI authentication. I know that I can customize everything to work as I want (so use session to store user data, etc.), but I wanted to know what the good practices are and which of them are provided out of the box with default WebAPI project in VS2013 and which need to be implemented manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) the latter is correct. The server verify token by machine key and can decipher and validate its contents.

(2)  You got that correct. Its best to keep the token size min. tbh I am looking to see what others are doing about this. (+1 for the question.)

Comment: After having spent a lot of time trying to figure all of this out myself, I've decided to override the authorize attribute to check roles. My users details will be cached when the token is issued. The users details will be keyed by the token+IP composite value (possibly the hash of it). When authorize is run, I will look these values up and process the action in my web api as necessary.